# Paste Excel Formula in the Loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I would like to paste this formula `=$F$6-E1` to cell range `A1` to `A10`, so it should be:

```
For A1 --> =$F$6-E1
For A2 --> =$F$6-E2
For A3 --> =$F$6-E3
For A4 --> =$F$6-E4
...
For A10 --> =$F$6-E10
```

First part is fixed, the other not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough, create a procedure, where for each cell in a specified range execute something.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub fill_formula(where As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each cell In where
        cell.Formula = "=$F$6 - E" & i
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Could be invoked a style of *(obviously you can pass a variable instead)*

```
Private Sub main()
    fill_formula (Sheets("Your sheet name").Range("A1:A10"))
End Sub
```

Fairly easy.
Though I don't see why this wouldn't be easier than to drag the formula manually, especially given this is referencing a static range (`E1` to `E[max]`)

Comment: @PetarPetrovic glad it helped, if you have any questions, let me know

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered but this can be done easily without a loop

```
With Sheet1
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(10, 1)).Formula = "=$F$6-E1"
End With
```

Gives the same result